# How to check and assign execute permission to the shell script files?

Tags: shell-script, permissions, find, chmod

I'm looking to write a .sh script to assign execute permission to all .sh files that have not been assigned execute permission in the current directory and subdirectories.

I can easily assign execute permission to all .sh files contained in the current directory and its subdirectories with just one command:

```
find -type f -iname '*.sh' -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

The above command will assign execute permission to all .sh files located in the current directory and subdirectories. But I just need the conditional statement to check if this .sh file has been assigned execute permission or not? If not, then execute the assign execute permission command for that file.

Your answer will be very helpful, I will appreciate your answer.

Comment: Why do you need to check? If the file is already executable, then `chmod +x` will simply do nothing.

Comment: @terdon checking before `chmod`ing will save unnecessary work from computer. (<- don't take it too serioulsy)

Comment: @Archemar  It is a serious point. With 1000 files, check and update 100, versus check and update 900, versus update 1000 unconditionally? I would actually expect an unconditional update to be less work in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`-executable` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Mode-Bits), negating it with `-not`

```bsh
$ ls -l
-rwxrwxr-x ... cmd.sh
-rw-rw-r-- ... foo.txt

$ find . -not -executable
./foo.txt
```

So in your case, you could do:

```
find -type f -iname '*.sh' -not -executable -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `-perm` option.

```
find . -perm /a=x
```

will match `x` bit `a`nywhere

So you need

```
find . -not -perm /a=x
```

which is an obscur form of accepted answer.

you can use

```
find -perm /go=x
```

to match file where either `g`roup or `o`ther is executable.

saddly you can't directly test missing bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check whether the files are executable or not.  The `chmod` command will not fail if the file already has the permissions that it is assigning. You don't save anything by first checking the permissions on the files.

The only change to your command that I would propose is to call `chmod` once for as many files as possible instead of once per file:

```bsh
find . -name '*.sh' -type f -exec chmod +x {} +
```

---

I also changed your non-standard `-iname` test to an ordinary `-name` test.  I'm assuming that you don't really have files with a mix of `.sh`, `.Sh`, `.sH`, and `.SH` filename suffixes.  If you have, you may want to fix them.  This does that:

```bsh
find . -type f -iname '*.sh' ! -name '*.sh' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        mv "$pathname" "${pathname%.??}.sh"
    done' sh {} +
```

Note that no check for filename collisions is made here.  If you are on a GNU system, you may want to use `mv -b` to produce backups in case there is a name collision.  As always, test random people's code on copies of backed-up data first.